# DHCP on Windows Server 2008 - Without Domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, dhcp, dhcp-server, ghost-image

Hi there I am experimenting with Ghost software (FOG Project). Since I have DHCP on my router (it's one of those routers you cannot configure.) I want to create a DHCP Server on my Windows Server 2008 so I can customise network booting.

I tried to setup DHCP on the server however I came across a snag. Because we run on a WORKGROUP I could not state a domain name to use. My question is - Is there a way to run a DHCP on Windows Server 2008 without setting up a domain or DNS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never ad any problem to setup a DHCP server into a workgroup. I even don't see where is your problem.
If this is when you have to type a domain name... then just type a domain name. Whatever you like. It is not used.

Beware about the fact a DHCP server on a standalone Windows 2008 server will stop if it detects an "authorized" DHCP server. This also could lead to memory consumption. You have to modify a registry value:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\DHCPServer\Parameters  REG_DWORD DisableRogueDetection = 1`